# How to do column alignment in openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to align a column in openpyxl without success:

```
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
```

....

```
ws.column_dimensions["A"].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left')
ws.column_dimensions["C"].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
```

The same for:

```
ws["A"].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left')
ws["C"].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
```

This isn't working for me.
Otherwise, iterating though cells and do alignment works correctly!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You should have gotten the failing Traceback!**
Please show us this if you post a question!

```
ws["A"].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left')
 AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'alignment'
```

Styling a *Range* or even *a whole column* is not implemented.
You have to do it on your own. For instance:

```
for row in rows:
    cell_A = row[:1][0]
    cell_A.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left')
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 4.3.3.2***

Comment: My question was about doing it without iterating the cells

Answer (score 6):

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

xlsx_file = 'file.xlsx'

# openning:
wb = load_workbook(filename = xlsx_file)

# center align column H in the default sheet:
ws = wb.active
for row in ws[2:ws.max_row]:  # skip the header
    cell = row[7]             # column H
    cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

# saving:
wb.save(xlsx_file)
```